# In which book and chapter does Harry Dresden use Lasciel to see in the dark?

Tags: the-dresden-files

This question involves minor spoilers involving Lasciel, read with caution.

There is a section in one of the books where,

> Harry has been kidnapped, locked to a wall with spiked anti-wizard manacles, and is being auctioned off to the highest bidder. He manages to convince Lasciel to help him without taking up the coin. To do so she tells him how to dislocate his thumbs and allows him to see in the dark using her ability to use a perfect version of Harry's memory.

In which book and chapter did this happen?

Answer (score 6):

That would be **Proven Guilty**, when Harry is taken captive by Madrigal Raith, in chapter 27.

> *Now*, I thought to Lasciel.
>   Darkness vanished, replaced with lines and planes of silver light that outlined the garage.

Comment: Missed it by *that* much.  Ah well, you already have more detail up so I'll take mine down.